# How do I select the highest column value in an SQL query IF another column is equal to a certain string

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to set up a matching system that selects the highest values of two different queries. I've looked at other answers on the site and they don't help. What I basically want to compare is:

I want to grab the highest value from the `version` column where `type` is equal to, for example "`type1`". I also want to grab the highest value from the `version` column where `type` is equal to "`type2`". I then want to compare these with PHP and find out if `type2`'s `version` is higher than `type1`'s `version`. Is there a way I can do this?

**EDIT:** This question has been answered by Brian Demilia. Can a moderator mark it as answered?

Comment: Sometimes I feel like I'm part of some vast social experiment.

Comment: @Zuris: I think he's referring to [this recent meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266350/has-stack-overflow-performed-any-social-experiments).

Comment: `SELECT type,MAX(version) FROM table WHERE type IN ('type1', 'type2) GROUP BY type` might be a starting point

Comment: @MarkBaker: I'll try that and update this comment and the post if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this will do what you want:

```
select version, type
  from tbl
 where version =
       (select max(version) from tbl where type in ('type1', 'type2'))
```

The type result column will show 'type1' if the max(version) was associated with a type1 record, or 'type2' if the max(version) was associated with a type2 record.

If you want to know the highest version for type1 and the highest version for type2 (as in,  you want the values brought back in output), and have the query identify which one is higher, you can use the following:

```
select t1.version as type1_max_version,
       t2.version as type2_max_version,
       case when t1.version > t2.version
            then t1.version
            else t2.version end as highest_version_num,
       case when t1.version > t2.version
            then 'type1'
            else 'type2' end as highest_version_type
  from tbl t1
 cross join tbl t2
 where t1.version = (select max(version) from tbl where type = 'type1')
   and t2.version = (select max(version) from tbl where type = 'type2')
```

Based on your comment if you wanted to filter in on only those rows where a field called "usrips" had certain values, you could use the following. This also assumes that you want to apply this filter to BOTH the type1 and type2 rows. Let me know if that is not the case. Also if you want to do additional fields in the WHERE clause, you'll need to add them to the JOIN clause between t1 and t2 as well, otherwise you'd have to repeat everything in the WHERE clause twice, once for t1 and once for t2

```
select t1.version as type1_max_version,
       t2.version as type2_max_version,
       case when t1.version > t2.version
            then t1.version
            else t2.version end as highest_version_num,
       case when t1.version > t2.version
            then 'Firewall'
            else 'FBypass' end as highest_version_type
  from tbl t1
  join tbl t2 on t1.usrips = t2.usrips
 where t1.version = (select max(version) from tbl
                      where type = 'Firewall' and usrips LIKE '%1.1.1.1%')
   and t2.version = (select max(version) from tbl
                      where type = 'FBypass'  and usrips LIKE '%1.1.1.1%')
   and t1.usrips LIKE '%1.1.1.1%'
```

See fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2525a/7/0

Comment: This suggestion does work, though I'm not sure how to add something like "**AND `usrIPs` LIKE %[IPHERE]%**" to only return them where `usrIPs` has [IPHERE] located anywhere inside it. Sorry, should have mentioned that in the question

Comment: The modification works rather well. I'm just having one little problem, though. If I remove the `usrIPs` column's data from one row, that row is still picked up by the query, even though it shouldn't

Comment: @Zuris I'm not sure what you mean, can you give an example w/ data? You can use http://sqlfiddle.com/ to provide examples of your table's data. When you say "remove the usrips column's data from one row" do you mean you're deleting something from the table or my query above?

Comment: What I mean is removing the usrIPs' column data from a row in the table, like row 4 (Highest `type2` value in the table). When I do that and run your query, it still picks up row 4

Comment: @Zuris are you sure that same IP doesn't also have a row with type1 and that it's coming back there? Or that there isn't another IP with a tie for that type2 value and that that IP isn't the one causing the output to be identical?

Comment: The database structure for the IPs is: (name-|-type-|-usrIPs) Windows_Firewall-|-Firewall-|-1.1.1.1 XPWall_23-|-Firewall-|-1.1.1.1 Waterwall-|-FBypass-|-1.1.1.1 Waterwall 2-|-FBypass-|-NULL . Waterwall 2 being picked up, though it shouldn't as it doesn't have 1.1.1.1 as an IP in its usrIPs cell

Comment: Waterwall has the same type (FBypass) so if Waterwall has the highest version after Waterwall2 is removed, then the version for Waterwall will show up. Can you post a fiddle? http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to make Waterwall's version show, but Waterwall 2's version is showing instead. And I attempted to make a fiddle, but didn't know how to save it

Comment: @Zuris there is a "link" button, after you hit it you can post the URL here. The link button is one of the blue buttons on the left frame

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90200/13/0 Here is the table (I'm not sure what you actually do with the SQLFiddle thing, so I just created you the table)

Comment: @Zuris I had forgotten the need to add the usrips criteria to the where clauses of each of the version subqueries (see my edit), a fiddle with the data you posted earlier is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2525a/7/0 , Waterfall 2 no longer contributes.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select max(case when t.type = 'type1' then version end) as type1_maxversion
       max(case when t.type = 'type2' then version end)  as type2_maxversion
from table t;
```

You can do the comparison in SQL, the easiest way is with a subquery:

```
select (case when type1_maxversion is null then 'No Type1'
             when type2_maxversion is null then 'No Type2'
             when type1_maxversion > type2_maxversion then 'Type1 Bigger'
             when type2_maxversion > type1_maxversion then 'Type2 Bigger'
             else 'equal'
        end) as comp
from (select max(case when t.type = 'type1' then version end) as type1_maxversion
             max(case when t.type = 'type2' then version end)  as type2_maxversion
      from table t
     ) x;
```